# kusto query in log analytics workbook

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

helo iam new to kusto query can i get the query for yesterday's date in log analytics workbook ?

```
let PGBARI1_Extraction_st = ADFPipelineRun
| where parse_json(Parameters).Process_Unique_RunID startswith "PGBARI1"
| where End >= Start
| where Start >= todatetime (strcat (tostring(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))
| summarize time1 = min(Start) by TenantId , process_name = 'PGBARI1';

 


let PGBARI1_Compaction_end = ADFPipelineRun
| where Parameters contains "PGBARI1"
| where _ResourceId endswith "df-pr-dna-eus2"
| where OperationName contains "orchestrator"
| where End >= Start
| where Start >= todatetime (strcat (tostring(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))
| summarize time2 = max(End) by TenantId , process_name = 'PGBARI1';

 


let PGBARI1 = PGBARI1_Extraction_st | join PGBARI1_Compaction_end on $left.process_name==$right.process_name
| summarize Runtime_in_minutes = sum( toint(datetime_diff('minute',time2,time1))), process_name = 'PGBARI1';

 


let PGBARI1_1 = ADFPipelineRun
| where Parameters contains "PGBARI1"
| where End >= Start
| where Start >= todatetime (strcat (tostring(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))
| where Status != 'Succeeded'
| summarize Failed = count(Status);
let PGBARI_Status = PGBARI1_1 | project Process_name = 'PGBARI1', Status = iff(Failed>0,'Failed','Succeeded');



PGBARI1 | union PGBARI_Status
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for, it will help if you will provide sample data using datatable() and the expected output.
As a side note,  this expression "todatetime (strcat (tostring(format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))" is the same as just using "startofday(now())"

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please describe your problem in more detail

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example